# Trying to connect to mLab, getting Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

I know this error is common when using local files, like C:// or files://, but the thing is, Im running my app on localhost, through http-server package.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://myuser:mypswd@ds225608.mlab.com:25608/todo-list-db')
```

Comment: Are you trying to use Mongoose in client-side javascript (i.e in the web browser)?

Comment: I have a server setup with Node.

Comment: Can you add the whole file where you try to connect using Mongoose to the question?

Comment: When you say you have a server set up with node, are you just talking about http-server or do you have something else?

Comment: this is what I have that should be my server. https://jsfiddle.net/dxupro2v/ (Tried do edit question, but couldnt, as stackoverflow was saying it was not properly indented or something)

Comment: Cool. How are you running this file and what's the exact output?

Comment: I am using pm2 and nodemon. It used to work, since I had mongod running, and using a local api. Now I am trying to migrate to mlab, as I want to deploy my app.

Comment: Okay, and you're getting the `Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes` error in your browser console?

Comment: that is correct.With my local api, everything works fine.

Comment: Okay, so this is less to do with connecting to MongoDB and more to do with trying to request resources from the client. From the client, you can only request resources using `http` and `https` (and some others but you're unlikely to use those). So you must be trying to connect to a resource that isn't using those schemes. What's the full error you're seeing? It should give you the URL it's trying to load and the line number where it is.

Comment: A common cause for this is if your client is trying to make a request to `localhost:8080/something`. You need to change that to a relative link such as `/something`.

Comment: I dont know what I should do, as the only thing I changed from when I was using local api, is the URL.

Comment: So `spread.js` is a script being run on the client. It's trying to make a request to a MongoDB URI. You shouldn't be trying to connect to a MongoDB URI on the client. Is `spread.js` doing what you expect it to be doing?

Comment: I dont really know where this `spread.js` file came from. I looked it up on my `node_modules` folder, and it seems to be a lib from axios. I dont know what it does or what I can do about it.

Comment: Are you requesting the MongoDB URI anywhere on the client side? Perhaps you are requesting it somewhere using axios?

Comment: Yes I am. It`s like I can connect, but cant request anything on client-side.

Comment: Okay, that's not how you want to connect to MongoDB. You should only connect to MongoDB using a driver (such as Mongoose) on the server-side. The client and the database should never talk directly. You want to have a web server (such as an Express server) in between. The client will make HTTP requests to the Express server, the Express server will talk to the database using Mongoose, then it will send the data back to the client.

Comment: Is this helpful? You might find a tutorial such as this useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs

Comment: Also wanted to mention: Since you've published your database username and password in your connection string, you should change those as soon as possible. People can access your database using those credentials.

Comment: Thank you very much! You were very helpful! I didnt know I had to enable api data acces on mlab settings. I can GET now, but still having some problems on PUT method.

Comment: Glad to hear you're making progress. But be careful using the mLab data API on the client-side. mLab strongly recommends using one of the MongoDB drivers to connect to your database instead of the data API. Your API key will give full access to all data within the databases belonging to your mLab account. So if you distribute it in client-side applications, people can gain access to your account and your data.

Comment: It's best practice to create an Express server that acts as an API between your client and your database (as described in the MDN tutorial I linked).

Comment: okay, I will dive deep into it. Im new to this nodeJS - DB connection thing. Cant say anything but thanks for your attention!